# Filemaker: Add record to table if not already there

Tags: filemaker

I have `CONTACT` table and `ZIPCODE` table which are related. I want a script so that if a user inputs `example_zipcode` which isn't in `ZIPCODE` table then `example_zipcode` is added to `ZIPCODE` table. In either case it should be stored in the `CONTACT` table.

*I have heard of* `isempty(field)`*, can I use this?*

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand why you'd be doing things like this. Is there lots of other information stored with the Zipcode (for example geographical coordinates)?

Are you happy for lots of invalid codes to be stored in the ZIPCODE table? What happens if a user types something very wrong like AUSTRALIA?

Also, how are the CONTACT and ZIPCODE tables related? By a primary/foreign key? Or just by the zipcode?

If there is nothing "magic" about a zipcode, I would probably put it straight into the CONTACT table.

```
CONTACT
-------
Name
Account Number
Zipcode
```

If you really want them in separate tables, perhaps do this:

```
CONTACT
-------
Name
Account Number
Zipcode

ZIPCODE
-------
Zipcode     (Unique)
```

You would then need a script that did the checking for you. You wouldn't need to use IsEmpty(field) in this case.

Perhaps your use case is as follows:

- User enters contact details, including zipcode
- You create the contact record, and, if necessary, the zipcode record

I would do it by using a script that the user clicks once they have entered a zipcode (or if you're using FileMaker 10, a Script Trigger on the Zipcode field).

The script would do something like this:

- Set Variable $zipcode CONTACT::Zipcode
- Go to Layout Zipcode
- Set Error Capture ON
- Enter Find Mind
- Set Field Zipcode $Zipcode
- Perform Find
- If (Get(Found Count) = 0)

  - New Record
  - Set Zipcode $Zipcode
  - Commit Records
- Go to Layout (Original Layout)

That, I think, would do what you asked, but there is likely a number of better solutions to solve your actual problem.